# how to install pip and virtualenv of python2.7 on rhel6?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, rhel, rhel6

I have **RHEL6-32bit** installed with default **python2.6**.
In that I installed **gcc**:

```
rpm -ivh ppl-0.10.2-11.el6.i686.rpm 
rpm -ivh cloog-ppl-0.15.7-1.2.el6.i686.
rpm -ivh mpfr-2.4.1-6.el6.i686.rpm
rpm -ivh cpp-4.4.7-18.el6.i686.rpm
rpm -ivh libgomp-4.4.7-18.el6.i686.rpm
rpm -ivh gcc-4.4.7-18.el6.i686.rpm
```

& **python2.7** as follows:

```
cd /usr/src 
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/Python-2.7.13.tgz
tar xzf Python-2.7.13.tgz
cd Python-2.7.13
./configure
make altinstall
```

Now I want to install **pip** and then **virtualenv** of python2.7. 
How do I enable python2.7 and install pip of python2.7?

Answer (score 0):

download get-pip.py file from following path using wget or any other tool

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

now execute downloaded get-pip.py file(ensure python path is provided in environment)

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157588/discussion-on-answer-by-mahesh-karia-how-to-install-pip-and-virtualenv-of-python).